# Assign css to only p not to specific p.class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In my html page there are two type of `<p>` -

- one is with `<p class="header"> for some Paragraph in header</p>`
- and others are just `<p>Containing some text </p>`

I want a `color` for the only `p` (should be some `#xxxxx`) and for `p.header` it should be the default color.

Here is my css:

```
p {
    margin-bottom:18px;
    line-height:180%;
    color:#xxxxx;
}
```

What I want is, this css should not get applied to `p.header` and it should use default style of browsers. Is there any way to select only `p` that are not in `p.header`?
like

```
      p:not("p.header"){ 
            margin-bottom:18px;
            line-height:180%;
            color:#xxxxx;
      }
```

Can we also use that like, `p:not(.header, .sub-title){}`?

Comment: Are we allowed to use JavaScript?

Comment: @JohnroePauloCañamaque: Yes, Probably that could be last option. I would expect in CSS.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not Check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 p:not(.header) { 
            margin-bottom:18px;
            line-height:180%;
            color:red;
 }
```

Just removed the quotation marks and the `p`

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8fbx5b2r/)

Comment: Can we also use that like, `p:not(.header, .sub-title)`?

Comment: No, what you can do is separate it using another pseudo-class/element. See http://jsfiddle.net/8fbx5b2r/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
p:not(.header) {


 your properties
}
```

That should works...